# Angular (click) events triggers host component re-rendering

Tags: angular, events, optimization, angular-changedetection

While trying to reduce useless component renders in an application I noticed Angular triggers changeDetection on click events, even for components with **ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush**

I've made a minimal example to reproduce the issue: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zdyxzx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Is there a way to limit renderings only on Input changes or async pipes updates ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call function in template it will get called each time Change Detection is triggered.
This is considered very bad practice and you should avoid it at all cost.
(Do a quick google on the topic, there are a lot of resources explaning this more into details)

The proper way to check when the component is rerendered you should use lifecycle hooks for instance ngOnChanges.

Comment: My question was why does change detection is triggered on that component when no input changed ? I was thinking ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush was preventing that.

Comment: Oh ok, I found an article explaining this in details. The ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush prevents change detection from events happening outside the component. Events happening inside still trigger change detection every time and all templates methods are called. Makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

`ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` does not prevent CD cycles to be triggered, it has just an influence on whether a component is actually checked during a CD cycle.

If you want to prevent CD to be triggered by a click event, you can configure `zone.js`. Take a look into your `polyfills.ts` file, there is a comment that explains how to do it. I have no experience with this myself though, and I am also not sure if this what you want to achieve, because it then applies to the whole application.

[image]